# how to use solr for existing mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, solr, indexing

I've a database which has lot of data and indexes. I want to use solr for this database. I've a log tables which has data in millions. If I use normal mysql queries, it is getting very very slow. So, I decided to use solr. But I'm new to solr.

Please someone help on this?

Comment: Well, read [the Reference Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Apache+Solr+Reference+Guide) or [the Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/) for a start. Have a special look at [the DataImportHandler](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler).

Answer (score 1):

At first configure schema http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml (there is no 'tables' in Solr, but documents and cores), than import data http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler. But keep in mind, that Solr is intended for full-text search and not a replacement for relational database.